# Displaying flash messages in rails if controller is called from jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

In my app i have a controller action with some code..

users_controller.rb

```
   def my_method(age)
     if age >18
      flash[:notice]= "You are eligible."
     else
      flash[:notice]= "You are not eligible."
     end
    end
```

I m calling my_method through jquery...(Coding is on Submit button of jquery dialog)

```
 jQuery.post('/users/my_method/', { age: jQuery('#age').val() });
```

But It is not displaying the flash messages, but in logs i have seen the method "my_method" is being called. Tell me how to display these flash messages?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an ajax request, you will have to handle the response by json (via rjs or something).

Following code will give you an example (this is one of my actual working code)

Ex: Adding a new friend

```
#friends_controller.rb
class FriendsController < ApplicationController
  #<other methods>
  def create
    @friend = Friend.new(params[:friend])
    if @friend.save
      flash.now[:success] = ["Friend request successfully sent"]
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    else
       render action: "new"   
    end
  end
end

#view/friends/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @friend, :remote => true do |f| %>
 #code
<% end %>

#view/friend/create.js.erb
$("#message_id").html("<%= escape_javascript raw(flash_display) %>");

note : flash_display is a helper method I used to display my messages

#helpers/application_helper.rb

def flash_display
    response = "<div class='alert #{alert_class}'>"
    response += "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>x</button>"
    flash.each do |name, msg|
      msg.each do |m|
        response = response + content_tag(:p, m)  
      end
    end
    response += "</div>"
    flash.discard
    response
end
```

Comment: message_id will be a controller(div or anything else) in layout?

Comment: its the div id of the message display html :)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax responses don't usually take advantage of flash messages.  Instead, look for the errors in the json.  This will get you started...

http://travisjeffery.com/b/2012/04/rendering-errors-in-json-with-rails/